# Best way to notify iOS app on server database updates

Tags: ios, web-services, tcp, apple-push-notifications

I am quite new into programming and I cant find efficient solution for my problem. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

I have an app which is heavily relying on server data. Data on server is unique for each user and may change every minute as well as only every few hours. Currently I am updating local data when app becomes active but I also need a way of notifying app to trigger updates when app stays in active state and data has changed on server. I thought about few solutions:

1) NSTimer set to one minute and triggering url request to check if there is new data on server. Server after comparing lastModified value would return new data if available.

- I don't really like that solution as I don't want to overload my server with number of requests, especially that data in the database may change only every few hours or even longer.

2) APNS - sending notifications from server every time data will change and than update local data with server database when notification received.

- It seems like a good solution but only if it would be possible to restrict remote notifications to be received when app is in active state. As far I know it is not possible and as I mentioned before data may change even every minute so I don't want to spam users with number of notifications when app is not running.

3) TCP Sockets using NSStream/CFStream?

- This is something I never did before, so I am not even sure if I am going in the right direction researching about this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hard topic in general, but more technologies are coming out to help with it. Couple thoughts on each of your solutions:

1. The NSTimer solution is effectively polling, which is the worst option I feel. You'd be hitting your server pretty hard for each user.
2. This would be a better solution. APNS now supports silent notifications, so you can send push notifications to a user without worrying about notifying them. You can send a silent notification by including the content-available key in the payload and not including the alert key. More info here: http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/. It is rate limited, though. You may go minutes to hours without getting a delivery, so if that's important you'd be best to go to option 3.
3. This is your best solution. It would require a persistent connection with your server. AFNetworking 2.0 supports this kind of connection based on Rocket. Here's Rocket's documentation: http://rocket.github.io. Take a look at server-sent events.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for late response. This is such a great answer. Finally I went for silent notifications and it works really nice so far.

Comment: @Guferos: Thanks for your comment, it cleared my confusion to which one option should I use APNs or Rocket (Persistent connection). By your comment, now I am confident enough to use APNs.